# curl fails to connect to the internet in Android

Tags: android

I have successfully built curl and a jni wrapper for it. However, when I execute the code in the emulator I get "Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'". If I provide the IP instead of a DNS name I get "couldn't connect to host". I am not behind a proxy so I have eliminated that possibility.

I am not sure if there is a setting in the emulator that I need to make to allow a native app to communicate with the internet. Any help would be appreciated. I have verified that connectivity to the internet exists via the adb shell.

> # nc -z -v www.google.com 80
>   DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.l.google.com != vw-in-f147.1e100.net
>   DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.l.google.com != vw-in-f103.1e100.net
>   DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.l.google.com != vw-in-f106.1e100.net
>   DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.l.google.com != vw-in-f105.1e100.net
>   DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.l.google.com != vw-in-f99.1e100.net
>   DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.l.google.com != vw-in-f104.1e100.net
>   www.l.google.com [74.125.113.147] 80 (www) open

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is very late reply, but googling information on this is so difficult that I though I add my input for the future googlers.

I have been working with the same problem and it seems that this is related to gethostbyname not working behind a proxy. In the environment where there are no proxies things seem to work fine. Also in my environment the proxy requires user name and password, so it may be even more difficult the get things working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the application manifest was missing permission to access the internet.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: This got me past connection issues. Now I am running into problems resolving the DNS if I provide a named host. It works fine if I provide and IP instead. I recompiled curl to use c-ares and now I get the following error "Could not resolve host: www.google.com (Could not contact DNS servers)". It cannot be the emulator configuration as the "nc" command resolves the host. So I assume there is something else in the application setup I am missing. If anyone has managed to get curl working in android, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work. In case anyone is interested it seems like this issue is present only when the jni shared lib is statically linked to curl and other dependents. It works fine when the shared libs are loaded dynamically.